# Matrix Multiplication Returing Array Index out of bound error

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, indexoutofboundsexception, filereader

This is one first post here, Pardon me if my question doesn't meet required standards here.

I have written a piece of code which takes input for two matrix from two separate files and performs multiplication and output the data to a new file.

It gives perfect output for 2x3 or 3x3 matrix. If i give input of 4x4 matrix i get array index out of bound runtime exception. I don't understand the reason as i dynamically create index

I get an array index out of bound exception at line 40.

I get an error.

![Snipet][2]

1. List item

   ```
   public class MM {




   private BufferedReader br;
   private int sum = 0;
   private final static String matrixA="matrixA.txt"; 
   private final static String matrixB="matrixB.txt";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new MM().MathMultiplicationValues(matrixA, matrixB);
   }

   private void MathMultiplicationValues(String mat1, String mat2) {
       try {
           br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mat1));          

           String line;
           int mat1rows = 0, mat1cols = 0, mat2rows = 0, mat2cols = 0;
           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               mat1cols = line.split(" ").length + 1;
               mat1rows++;
           }
           br.close(); // To close file
           br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mat2)); // to read input from file.
           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               mat2cols = line.split(" ").length + 1;
               mat2rows++;
           }
           int[][] mat1vals = new int[mat1rows ][mat1cols ]; 
       int[][] mat2vals = new int[mat2rows ][mat2cols ]; 
           br.close();
           br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mat1));
           for (int i = 1; i < mat1rows + 1; i++) {
               line = br.readLine();
               String[] colvals = line.split(" ");
               for (int j = 1; j < mat1cols; j++) {
                   mat1vals[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(colvals[j - 1]);

               }

           }


           br.close();
           br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mat2));
           for (int i = 1; i < mat2rows + 1; i++) {
               line = br.readLine();
               String[] colvals = line.split(" ");
               for (int j = 1; j < mat2cols; j++) {
                   mat2vals[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(colvals[j - 1]);

               }


           }

           br.close();
           if ((mat1cols-1) == mat2rows) { 
               int[][] resltmat = new int[mat1rows + 1][mat2cols + 1];
               for (int i = 1; i < mat1rows + 1; i++) { //Loop does matrix multiplication. 
                   for (int j = 1; j < mat1cols; j++) {
                       for (int k = 0; k < mat2rows + 1; k++)
                           sum = sum + mat1vals[i][k] * mat2vals[k][j];
                       resltmat[i][j] = sum;
                       sum = 0;
                   }
               }

               final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("Answer.txt"); //Creates a new file called Matrix Answer. 
               for (int i = 1; i < mat1rows + 1; i++) 
               {

                   for (int j = 1; j < mat2cols; j++) {
                       pw.print(resltmat[i][j] + " "); // Writes the output to file the file called MatrixAnswer

                   }
                   pw.println();

               }
               pw.close();
           } else // If no of columns not equal to rows control passes to else block. 
               System.out.println("Multiplication of Matrix is not possible because columns are not equal to rows");

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();

       }
   }

   }
   ```

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but what might help is to separate the (overly long in my opinion) method (which as an aside should also be named in lower camelCase) into smaller routines. Not only will it be more readable, but it will allow you to write smaller unit tests that will help you pinpoint the source of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Might be because of this

```
for (int i = 1; i < mat1rows + 1; i++) {
    line = br.readLine();
    String[] colvals = line.split(" ");
    for (int j = 1; j < mat1cols; j++) {
        mat1vals[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(colvals[j - 1]);

    }

}
```

`i = mat1rows` on the last iteration which is OOB. Change `for (int i = 1; i < mat1rows + 1; i++)` to `for (int i = 1; i < mat1rows; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

As you used in the allocation, the dimension of the resulting matrix are `mat1rows` x `mat2cols`. Thus in the computation of `resltmat[i][j]` the index `i` has bound `mat1rows` (check) and the index `j` has the upper bound `mat2cols` (fail). Thus change the range of `j` from `mat1cols` to `mat2cols`.

Comment: Thanks Lutz. Your comment is highly appreciated, But still i have a problem in code

Comment: Your code is fundamentally correct, you only have to sort out the correct dimensions and how to incorporate them into the loop bounds. You should not have to use `resltmat = new int[mat1rows + 1][mat2cols + 1];`, because that is one too many in both directions. Or if you do, make sure that all loops are 1-based, i.e., not starting with `0`.